# Clone github project to local machine (Mac) with a second github account

Tags: github

I have configured my machine to use one account for a github project for a while now.  Now I am going to start participating in another project and decided to use a different github account.

I tried to set the configuration for the new repository locally, but it didn't seem to help:

```
$ mkdir github
$ cd github/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/.../Sites/.../github/.git/
$ git config user.name "..."
$ git config user.email "..."
$ git config github.user SECOND ACCOUNT NAME
$ git config github.token SECOND ACCOUNT TOKEN
$ git clone git@github.com:.../....git
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/.../Sites/.../github/.../.git/
ERROR: Permission to .../... denied to FIRST_ACCOUNT.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another Unix-user to work on that second project, that would minimise complication. Else you would have to change the email-address back and forth (as Github connects the commit and the account by comparing the email-addresses and would thus probably refer to the wrong account in the commit).

To the connection issue: Have you uploaded your SSH key to Github for the second account?

Comment: Ack, I haven't added the SSH key yet.  

Is it possible to have two keys?  The first account already has it in .ssh/id_rsa and id_rsa.pub...

Comment: It is perfectly possible to have two SSH keys on Github. Head over to “Account Settings”, then click on “SSH Public Keys” and press “Add another key”. Hope that helped!